# Timeout error when retrieving data from firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with react native and I retrieving data in the following way:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('myDbCollection').get();
```

I changed the rules in firebase to allow everyone to read from the DB.

When the get request is executed I get:

[image: Timeout Error]

A second after the error pop ups I get all the requested data in the console. Also when I write in firestore it works fine.
Is my sintaxis to retrieve data correct?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting everything rather than filtering and only getting what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this problem in the future I recommend to test it on a mobile device because I restarted the emulator twice and no luck. After restarting the computer the code began to work with no changes whatsoever.